# Difference between gettype() and get_debug_type() in PHP8.1?

Tags: php, php-8, php-8.1

What is the exact difference between `gettype()` and `get_debug_type()`?

Official documentation describes it, but too vague for me:

- `gettype()`: *Get the type or object name of a variable*
- `get_debug_type()`: *Get the type of a variable*

Comment: First hit when I googled it: https://www.amitmerchant.com/get-type-of-varibale-using-get-debug-type-function-in-php8/

Answer (score 1):

Both functions are generally used for **variable debugging** and to get the **`type`** of a given **variable**.

The main difference is:

> **`get_debug_type()`** differs from **`gettype()`** in that it returns type names that are more consistent with actual usage, rather than
> those present for historical reasons.

---

**`gettype()`** returns one of the following possible string values:

- "boolean"
- "integer"
- "double" (for historical reasons "double" is
  returned in case of a float, and not simply "float")
- "string"
- "array"
- "object"
- "resource"
- "resource (closed)" as of PHP 7.2.0 "NULL"
- "unknown type"

---

**`get_debug_type()`** returns one of the following possible string values:

| Type + State | Return Value |
| --- | --- |
| null | "null" |
| Booleans (true or false) | "bool" |
| Integers | "int" |
| Floats | "float" |
| Strings | "string" |
| Array | "array" |
| Resources | "resource (resourcename)" |
| Resources (Closed) | "resource (closed)" |
| Objects from Named Classes | The full name of the class including its namespace e.g. Foo\Bar |
| Objects from Anonymous Classes | "class@anonymous" |

Sources:

- https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.get-debug-type.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.gettype.php